# Ohm's Law for Accelerated Conductors

Tags: electromagnetism, special-relativity

My questions are about the Ohm's law for a moving conductor in a stationary magnetic field. As we know this law is stated based on following relation with respect to the fixed frame of reference linked to the laboratory:

$${\mathbf J}=\sigma({\mathbf E}+{\mathbf v} \times {\mathbf B})$$

In which, ${\mathbf v}$ is the velocity vector of conductor, and ${\mathbf E}$ and ${\mathbf B}$ are the field vectors of the stationary electromagnetic field.

1. How can we use this equation for accelerated conductors in the lab frame while this equation is proved by the Lorentz transformation which is based on assuming a constant relative velocity between the two inertial frames when $v/c\rightarrow 0 $?

   In the conductor's rest frame of reference: ${\mathbf J'}=\sigma {\mathbf E'}$

   ${\mathbf J'} = {\mathbf J}$ and ${\mathbf E'} = {\mathbf E}+{\mathbf v} \times {\mathbf B}$ when ${\mathbf v}$=const. and $v/c \rightarrow 0$

   then we conclude ${\mathbf J}= \sigma ({\mathbf E}+{\mathbf v} \times {\mathbf B})$ in the lab's fixed frame.

   I ask this because I looked at several text books in the magnetohydrodynamics which use this
   equation to study magnetic fluids which have obviously chaotic and accelerated motions. Unfortunately, the authors did not clarify this matter and I am confused!
2. The Lorentz force ${\mathbf F} = q({\mathbf E}+ {\mathbf v} \times {\mathbf B})$ has a similar form, and is used to study accelerated charges and conductors, ${\mathbf F} = m {\mathbf a}$. As far as I know this law is based on experimental evidence and can also be proved by special relativity assuming a constant velocity between the two inertial frames. I read some papers or texts which use the term "instantaneously at rest" to deal with accelerated charges? What does that mean exactly?

I would be very thankful if you answer my questions and introduce me a well-written reference book to understand these issues profoundly.

Comment: "*...I looked at several text books...*" Which ones?

Comment: I looked at: http://www.amazon.com/Introduction-Magnetohydrodynamics-Cambridge-Applied-Mathematics/dp/0521794870/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1416974104&sr=1-1&keywords=An+Introduction+to+Magnetohydrodynamics , http://www.amazon.com/Magneto-Fluid-Dynamics-Fundamentals-Phenomena-Astrophysics/dp/0387335420 and some lectures on the web in PDF forms.

Comment: I am a PhD student in structural engineering and interested in this topic. I have a general knowledge about the special relativity and electromagnetism. I read the Griffiths' book and some other books. But, all the texts I have read talk about conductors with constant velocity!.